# React : Save value after edit

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React.js and React InlineEdit. I want to edit a text, and save the new value of text
This is my code :

```
//{etape.title} is not empty
<InlineEdit
validate={this.customValidateText}
activeClassName="editing"
text={etape.title} 
paramName="message"
change={this.dataChanged}
/>



dataChanged(text) {      
        this.setState({          
            editStep: text.target.value
        })
    }

 customValidateText(text) {
        return (text.length > 0 && text.length < 64);
    }
```

So I can edit my text, but when i click on the text, the value bu défault come back, and not the value edited.

How can I do that ? 
Thank you

Comment: did you try this: `change = {(text) => this.dataChanged(text)}`

Comment: Yes but i have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably a context error. 
Try one of the following :

```
change = {(text) => this.dataChanged(text)}
```

or

```
dataChanged = text => {
        this.setState({
            editStep: text.target.value
        })
    }
```

---

Try this then :

```
<InlineEdit
validate={this.customValidateText}
activeClassName="editing"
text={this.state.message} 
paramName="message"
change={this.dataChanged}
/>
```

In your constructor :

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { 
       //what you had in your state
       message: //The initial value you had in etape.title
}
```

And finally :

```
dataChanged = (data) => {
        this.setState({...data})
    }
```

Comment: first one should be `change = {(text) => this.dataChanged(text)}`, a normal function calling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i'm trying your solution, and it dosn't work, i have the same result...

Comment: As @alix said, might be helpful to have the whole code.

Comment: The code is juste a form with field. I'm trying to test the inlineEdit without other code, and it's the same problem

Answer (score 0):

if you do not bind `dataChanged` method in `constructor` method, try;

```
<InlineEdit
    validate={this.customValidateText.bind(this)}
    activeClassName="editing"
    text={etape.title} 
    paramName="message"
    change={this.dataChanged.bind(this)} />
```

As @Victor mentioned, it might be a context issue. Better if you show your whole component code.

Answer (score 0):

As per [DOC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-edit-inline#usage-example):

**change function will return an object**, that will contain a key that you defined in `paramNames` (in your case `message`) and that key will contain the value edited by user. So you need to write it in this way:

```
<InlineEdit
    validate={this.customValidateText.bind(this)}
    activeClassName="editing"
    text={etape.title} 
    paramName="message"
    change={(data) => this.dataChanged(data)} />

dataChanged(data) {
    console.log(data)
    this.setState({editStep: data.message})
}
```

It should work.

Check the detail of required props: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-edit-inline#required-props

Comment: No , I've tested that, but I'v the same problem